# Objective C compile error "No matching constructor for initialisation type"

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to implement this code but i got a compile error in Xcode: 
"No matching constructor for initialisation of 'PlaybackDelegate'"
"Assigning to 'PlaybackDelegate *' from incompatible type 'PlaybackDelegate'"

I copy/pasted the code from an example that does work. But I can't figure out why it's not working in my project.

```
header file
class PlaybackDelegate : public IDeckLinkVideoOutputCallback
{
DecklinkDevice*             pDecklinkDevice;

public:
    PlaybackDelegate (DecklinkDevice* owner);

virtual HRESULT QueryInterface (REFIID iid, LPVOID *ppv) {return E_NOINTERFACE;}
virtual ULONG AddRef () {return 1;}
virtual ULONG Release () {return 1;}

virtual HRESULT ScheduledFrameCompleted (IDeckLinkVideoFrame* completedFrame, BMDOutputFrameCompletionResult result);
virtual HRESULT ScheduledPlaybackHasStopped ();
};
```

.mm file

```
playerDelegate = new PlaybackDelegate(self, deckLinkOutput);

if (playerDelegate == NULL)
{
    //NSLog(@"fout completed frame callback");
    //fout
}
```

---

```
PlaybackDelegate::PlaybackDelegate (DecklinkDevice* owner)
{
pDecklinkDevice = owner;
}

HRESULT PlaybackDelegate::ScheduledFrameCompleted (IDeckLinkVideoFrame* completedFrame, BMDOutputFrameCompletionResult result)
{
    NSLog(@"Frame Completed");
return S_OK;
}

HRESULT PlaybackDelegate::ScheduledPlaybackHasStopped ()
{
return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see a PlaybackDelegate constructor in your code that takes two arguments ...

Comment: hmm indeed.. looked over this one for 2 hours but it works now. many thx!